# Slicing torch tensors with list of indeces

Tags: python, pytorch, slice

I'm doing a reinforcement learning project, and I'm trying to get a tensor that represents the expected reward of all the given actions. I have a long tensor of chosen actions of size `batch` with values of either zero or one (the two potential actions). I have a tensor of expected rewards for each action of size `batch * action_size`, and I want a tensor of size `batch`.

For example, if batch size was 4, then I have

```
action = tensor([1,0,0,1])
expectedReward = tensor([[3,7],[5,9],[-1,12],[0,1]])
```

and what I want is

```
rewardForActions = tensor([7,5,-1,1])
```

I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989310/can-i-slice-tensors-with-logical-indexing-or-lists-of-indices) would answer my question, but it's not the same at all, because if I went with that solution, it would end up with a 4*4 tensor, selecting from each row 4 times, instead of once.

Any ideas?

Comment: The solution with torch.index_select() actually gives the vector I want, except it's along the diagonal of the output 4*4 tensor, instead of as a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
rewardForActions = expectedReward.index_select(1, action).diagonal()  
# tensor([ 7,  5, -1,  1])
```